# C# MP4 video creation from images and mp3 file

Tags: c#-4.0, directshow, mp4

I am creating videos from series of images with an audio mp3 using splicer (http://splicer.codeplex.com/). The output for this is avi and use ffpmpeg to convert to mp4.

Is there any api for c# to create mp4 from series of images and mp3 file. I need to add some animation as well like Ken Burns style this time.

Answer (score -1):

DirectShow Editing Services - best way. Or DirectShow using push source filter sample to generate frames. In both cases MP4 muxer, H264 and AAC encoders required.
Codecs can be purchased from Elecard for example - http://www.elecard.com/en/products/development/sdk/codec-sdk.html .

Alternative commercial solution to create video from images and encode to MP4 using a few lines of code - http://www.visioforge.com/video-edit-sdk-net.html .

Comment: From MSDN it looks like DirectShow Editing Services is or will get depricated. I am also having difficulty find good tutorials for it. I will try visioforge though